# Ajax call inside an ajax success not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make an Ajax call inside another Ajax success function but it somehow doesn't work. I get the following error in my console. I don't understand what it means:

> Object { readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: .ajax/v.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/v.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/v.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/v.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/v.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/v.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always: .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), 10 more… }

**I found something like below from the object**

> statusText:"SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified"

**JS**

```
 //Update the board with the moves so far made
    var updateBoard = function() {
        var style;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "engine/main.php",
            data: {code: 2},
            success: function(response) {
                if(response != "") {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                    lastClick = obj[obj.length - 1].player;
                    $(obj).each(function (i, val) {
                        if (val.player == 1) {
                            style = "cross";
                        }
                        else if (val.player == 2) {
                            style = "circle";
                        }
                        $('td[data-cell="' + val.cell + '"]').html(val.sign).addClass(style);
                    });

                    if(obj.length > 2) {
                        makeDecision();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    lastClick = null;
                    $('td').html("").removeClass();
                }
                setTimeout(updateBoard, 1000);
            }
        });
    };
    updateBoard();

function makeDecision() {
        console.log('starting decision function');
        $.ajax({
            type: "engine/main.php",
            data: {code: 3},
            success: function(winner) {
                console.log('end');
                console.log(winner);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['code'])) {
    $code = $_POST['code'];
    //Handle player number on game start
    if($code == 1) {
        if (!isset($_COOKIE['gamePlay'])) {
            header('Location: index');
        }
        $playerCode = $_COOKIE['gamePlay'];
        $player = $playersHandler->getPlayer($playerCode);
        echo $player;
    }
    // Update board with new moves
    else if($code == 2) {
        $currentPosition = $gameHandler->getMoves();
        echo $currentPosition;
    }
    else if($code == 3) {
        $result = $code; //$gameHandler->decide();
        echo $result;
    }
    //Reset Board
    else if($code == 4) {
        $gameHandler->reset();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is output on `console.log(response);`?

Comment: You mean inside the first ajax success call? Then it is an JSON array.

Comment: Which line is the error happening on? Likely either `response` isn't valid JSON, `val.cell` isn't valid in a jQuery selector, or `val.sign` isn't valid HTML.

Comment: After the first success call,  `makeDecision function` is entered but then the ajax call inside that function gives the error as mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing an invalid string to `type` property inside the `makeDecision` function ajax call. You should set this as following:

```
type: 'POST',
url: 'engine/main.php',
...
```

instead of

```
type: 'engine/main.php'
```

---

Make sure that the following line

```
var obj = JSON.parse(response);
```

returns an **array**, not an object. If `obj` is not an array, then `obj.length` is `undefined`

Comment: Oh! yes you are correct!! Exactly! I made a mistake there..Damn!! But still I don't get the required output

Comment: if you see the PHP snippet am assigning the `$code` to `$result` but in my console I get blank.

Comment: Are you sure that "obj.length > 2" is true and the second ajax call gets executed? Unfortunately, I am not able to debug without an actual working example :)

Comment: I just logged my `obj.length` in the first ajax success call after parsing the json response and currently it is 3. And then I logged ouput as `starting decision function` inside `makeDecision` and it also got logged. Even I got the ouput from its success function but its just BLANK.

Comment: logging the `obj` I get this `[{"cell":"0","sign":"✘","player":1},{"cell":"4","sign":"◯","player":2},{"cell":"2","sign":"✘","player":1}]`

Comment: Try to hardcode the response inside PHP script ( like: echo "test" ) to see if you get anything inside ajax success callback

Answer (score 0):

You can call ajax again inside the ajaxComplate event like this:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
   $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: 'engine/main.php',
            data: {code: 3},
            success: function(winner) {
                console.log('end');
                console.log(winner);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Why `document`? Actually I make more than one Ajax request in my script so will document work?

Comment: Yes, it will work. and if you want to add Ajax event again inside Ajax then you can use ajaxComplate event for that.

Comment: How can I attach the event handler to the updateBoard function.

Comment: You can use `complete` event in ajax function like that `complete: function(e) {
console.log("After complete");
}`

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna that means, success function will be there plus a complete function to be added?

Comment: you can do that in your `complete` event or you can do that in your `success` event. I think the issue was @kapantzak said.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get length of object directly `obj.length` in javascript.So if you are getting response properly.Get length of Parsed object like this..

```
var length = Object.keys(obj).length;
```

Then

```
lastClick = obj[length-1].player;
```

Make correct use of `$.each` like this..

```
$.each(obj,function (i, val){
//code

});
```